# ajax post reload page

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

My index.jsp page, load my form with this line of code :

```
 $('#box').load('/Edit_Data.jsp?id=' + myID);
```

Then, I can correctly edit the data presents in the form. When I've finished, I click on a button that triggers this function :

```
function save() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
  cache: false,
     url: '/Edit_data',
    data: $('form[name="formData"]').serialize(),
  complete : function(jqXHR,textStatus) {
    alert("complete " + jqXHR.responseText );
    },
  error: function(jqXHR,textStatus){
        alert("status " + textStatus + ", response :" + jqXHR.responseText);
     }
   });
```

}

and my java servlet for the path "/Edit_data", return this :

```
  resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
  resp.setContentType("text/xml");
  String xml = "<report><error_msg></error_msg></report>";
  resp.getWriter().println(xml);
```

The behavior after I clicked on the button is :

1. The request is correctly sent
2. I receive the error alert message : status error, response :
3. Then, I receive the complete message :complete     (the responseText is null)
4. Finally, it reloads my index.jsp page with a Get request with the parameters that I sent to the servlet. Like that : http://localhost:8888/index.jsp?name=test&firstname=test

My problem is : why after the ajax request has been done, the index.jsp page is reloaded. The correct behavior should be : after the request, nothing sould be done because I handle the complete function

One clue should be the error message returned by the servlet, but I can't see the full content of the error so I don't understand what triggers the error...

One other important clue, I only have this problem with firefox and chrome. It works correctly for IE.

Could you help me to solve that?

Thank you very much,

Bat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ajax means asynchronous request... 
It should not reload ideally,If you didn't do any mistake. 
Well, you can use `return false;`
Or on calling ajax function `onclick="return AjaxFunction();` For your case it might be : `onclick="return save();`

Hope this will solve your issue.

Cheers!

Comment: The solution was to add this into the form tag : onSubmit="return false;"

Answer (score 4):

Looks like your form gets submitted the "classic" way, because you are not preventing the form's default action. Try adding a `return false` to the end of your save function, or binding a handler to your form's `submit` event:

```
$("#theForm").submit(function (e) {

    // prevent normal submit behaviour
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: 6 Threads later, this is the answer I needed.  All the other posts assume that we are using that xml redirector, but it was the form submittal that was doing that piece, so preventing the default action so I could map my own was the trick.  Thanks!